# adjust cell width to content in tabular* environment

Tags: tables

I have a two-column tabular* environment and I wish to automatically adjust the  width of the first cell of each row to its content. How do I remove the horizontal space "x" in the attached image?

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} % 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}
    {\textwidth}{ll}}{%
    \end{tabular*}}
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
{#1}&\parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}}\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2017 Sept~-~%\dots
    a very long date here}{ABC Position}{City, Country}%
    {\blindtext}    
    \twentyitem{2015 May~-~%\dots
    2017 Sept}{XYZ Position}{City, Country}%
    {\blindtext}    
\end{twenty}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, that is not a good way to write a CV.

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ll}}` can not work, you are specifying the table be stretched but adding no flexibility. If you use `tabular*` you _have_ to use `\extracolsep` to add stretchy space between the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a new `tabularx` environment for every entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myentry}[4]{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}#1 & \textbf{#2} \hfill #3 \newline #4 \\ \end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\myentry{2017 Sept - a very long date here}{ABC position}{City, Country}{\blindtext}
\myentry{2015 May~-~2017 Sept}{XYZ Position}{City, Country}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `right alignment` for the first column.

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}
    {\textwidth}{rl}}{%
    \end{tabular*}}
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
{#1}&\parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}}\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{twenty}
    \twentyitem{2017 Sept~-~%\dots
    a very long date here}{ABC Position}{City, Country}%
    {\blindtext}
    \twentyitem{2015 May~-~%\dots
    2017 Sept}{XYZ Position}{City, Country}%
    {\blindtext}
\end{twenty}
\end{document}
```

[image]